# Java interface design

Tags: java

I had an interface initially as below.

```
public interface testMe {
      public Set<String> doSomething();
}
public class A implements testMe {
      public Set<String> doSomething() {
           return // Set<String>
      }
}
```

I had similar classes implementing testMe. Now I have to add one more class which returns `Set<Some Object>`

```
public class X implements testMe() {
     public Set<Some OBject> doSomething() {
     }
}
```

How could i add this method in the interface without breaking existing classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't for two reasons.

1. A class or interface can't have two or more methods that have the same number and type of parameters with the same name but differing return types; and
2. Because of type erasure, all `Set<...>` instances are, at runtime, simply `Set`, so they would have the exact same return type anyway.

You will need to name the second something different.

The more complicated answer is that you can make the parameter type extensible:

```
public interface TestMe<T extends Serializable> {
  Set<T> doSomething();
}

public class A implements TestMe<String> {
  @Override
  public Set<String> doSomething() { ... }
}

public class X implements TestMe<ASerializableObject> {
  @Override
  public Set<ASerializableObject> doSomething() { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
public interface testMe {
   public Set<?> doSomething();
}
```

Or

```
public interface testMe {
   public Set<? extends CommonSuperclass> doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can, because type erasure will ruin the effect you have in mind.

You can parameterize the interface:

```
import java.util.Set;

public interface ISomething<T>
{
    Set<T> doSomething(T [] data);
}
```

And the implementation:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Something<T> implements ISomething<T>
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Something<String> something = new Something<String>();

        Set<String> set = something.doSomething(args);
        System.out.println(set);
    }

    public Set<T> doSomething(T [] data)
    {
        Set<T> foo = new HashSet<T>();

        for (T x : data)
        {
            foo.add(x);
        }

        return foo;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure this accomplishes what you have in mind, though.

Comment: The problem here is, I do not instantiate the concrete classes directly but encapsulated in factory method. How would one write factory method around it returning ISomething<String> as well as ISomething<Some Object>. If we parameterize even the factory, then the problem is moved to the consumer of the method. It has to decide what is returned.